# Retrieving Content from All Cells in an .ipynb File Using VSCode Extension Development

Tags: vscode-extensions

When developing a VSCode extension, the document.getText() method from the provideInlineCompletionItems function in the InlineCompletionItemProvider interface returns only the content of the current cell in an .ipynb file. How can I retrieve the content from all the preceding cells?